# PHP Doctrine - select uuid stored in binary(16) as hex

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, uuid

I've made custom doctrine type for storing UUID in BINARY(16), it is working well but I have a problem when selectin records.

I need to select id as HEX(id), but doctrine can't do it (or it can, but i have not found the way)... is there a way to force doctrine to select id as HEX(id)?

I am using MYSQL.

Thanks

Comment: I think UUID is CHAR(32)

Comment: Yes, UUID is implicitly stored as CHAR. But MYSQL are storing primary key in every index above the table - so char(32) in utf8 is 96b...if there will be 96b primary key and 2 foreign keys it will be 96 + 2 * (96+96) = 480b.

For 100M records its around 48GB... there are also some performace issues when storing primary key as CHAR... that's why i want to store it as BINARY(16).